# Media query works in devtools except when run on a mobile device

Tags: css

CSS media queries I've made for portrait phone screens works in devtools, here is a link to it:

https://streamable.com/hz6xhf

However, it doesn't replicate when it is viewed on my phone's browser, this is what it looks like on that device:

[image]

**Live:** https://ganznz.github.io/tempestas/dist/

**Repo:** https://github.com/ganznz/tempestas/tree/gh-pages

**.css file:** https://github.com/ganznz/tempestas/blob/gh-pages/src/main.css

Comment: It works fine on mobile as I tested and it's not a responsive meta tag problem.

Comment: Works on my iPhone in portrait mode. What device, browser and OS is it not working on?

Comment: You should post your code directly here instead of pasting links

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement some media queries between 450 to 650px as using devtools to shrink it to 450-650px it overflows and looks just like on your screenshot, or just extend the 450px one to 650px.